# Expected Value of $e^{t+W(t)/2}$ where $W(t)$ is the Wiener process.

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, means

I'm trying to calculate the expected value of this stochastic process that has the Wiener process. $E(U(t)) = e^{9t/8}$ is the answer.

$ E(U(t)) = E(e^{t+W(t)/2})$ where $W(t)$ is the Wiener process. So far I have:
$$ E(U(t)) = E(e^{t+W(t)/2})$$
$$ = e^t E(e^{W(t)/2}) $$

I think I can use the integral of $W(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-t^2/2}}{\sqrt{(2\pi)}} dt$ but what's throwing me is that it's divided by $2$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It suffices to know the moment generating function of the normal distribution. This is computed by completing the square in the course of doing a Gaussian integral.

Comment: I'm just not sure what it looks like as a start. Is it $ e^{x/2} e^{-x^2/2}/ \sqrt{2\pi} $ ?

Comment: You want to compute $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} t} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{x/2} e^{-x^2/2t} dx$ (and then multiply it by $e^t$). The way to do this is to complete the square in $x/2-x^2/2t$.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ian above is right. MGF is the way to go. Look up MGF, $E(e^{xt})$, for Normal and set $t=1$. You will see when $x$ is Normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, the expectation of $e^x$ is $e^{\mu+\sigma^2/2}$. For your process, $\mu$ is $t$ and Var($x$) is $t/4$.